# Short story about device that tells user the best action to take in any given situation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this story someone gets an ear piece that tells him exactly what the best thing to do would be to get a promotion at work or whatever. Over time he and this device develop their own language instead of English to be more efficient, so eventually it's effectively transmitting "binary signals" at him, controlling his every move.

I read it somewhere on the internet. I could've sworn the device was called a "Conch" and I think the webpage with the story had a small picture of a shell too.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Sf&f, do you remember when you read this story or any further details about the main character and the different ways in which the device helped him?

Comment: @shanu call it 5-10 years ago. I don't remember the story at all besides what I wrote, even the "get a promotion" just felt intuitively similar to what happens in the story, but not what happened. It might be related to the AI community and the [Less Wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LessWrong) people but maybe not.

Comment: This was a lesser known, self published on the internet story. It might've even been a forum post? I think I remember clicking through more than one page but maybe not. The page was pretty visually dense text, not like Medium today or whatever. The picture of the conch I think was like a [flat spiral kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escargot_de_Quimper) (just a random shell I found), I think it was more of a shape, minimal visual details white shell on a light blue background, something like `#9edee7`, but I could be totally imagining this image, I think I made up the color just now.

Comment: I thought "the conch" was the name of the story and it was the first thing I googled looking for it. I live in Canada and that's not a word I hear often here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device involved is initially built as a memo system, has a different form factor, and is called a "tickler", but a partial match is Fritz Leiber's "[The Creature from the Cleveland Depths](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/23164/23164-h/23164-h.htm)". Cribbing from my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147254/looking-for-the-short-story-personal-robot-assistants-sitting-on-ones-shoulder?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> An engineer devises a little clockwork/tape-based thing where a man can make notes and reminders, and the device would give the wearer a slight shock, a "tickle" when the time hit, reminding him to check his appointments. His friend, a marketer, stole the idea (which he was noted as doing often, something the protagonist cheerfully grumbled about) and released it, claiming his company had been working on it all the time. As time went on, the tickler was improved to also automatically remind a person to do routine chores, and to even inject drugs to help make them happier. By the end of the story, the engineer, who has refused the tickler, realizes that the ticklers have taken over.

Comment: I think you're right, thanks

Comment: Huh. I thought this was only a "if you're looking for something similar..." answer. :-D If, after reading it (the first link is to the Project Gutenberg copy), you feel it's not a match, don't be afraid to un-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.